# Execute the output of an SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, insert, exec

I have a stored procedure 'GetInsertTrigger' which returns below Output.

[image]

I need to concat these lines and execute it again.
Also, I cannot insert this output into temp table.

```
create table   #otable  (line nvarchar(max))
insert into #otable (line)
exec GetInsertTrigger @TableName = 'cci_parms_mst'
```

Error msg is

```
Msg 8164, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetInsertTrigger , Line 1266 [Batch Start Line 64]
An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.
```

I cannot modify `GetInsertTrigger` as it is standard in our system.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. *"which returns table having another code inserted in different lines."* what does that mean? *"I need to concat these lines and execute it again."* which lines? *"which returns this type of data."* which type of data? The final error message is pretty clear: you cannot nest `INSERT EXEC`, although why you would ever want to is beyond me. Perhaps you should be using views or inline Table Functions instead of procedures? Also `IF ... GO` makes no sense as `GO` is not a command, it's a batch separator

Comment: @Charlieface I have updated the question. If you know any approach to insert the output into temp table, let me know.

Comment: Please don't paste in images, we can't copy them. Sorry didn't realize: your procedure returns the *code* of a trigger as a resultset one line at a time?? Why would it do this, what purpose does it serve? It should return a single value (possibly in a `output` parameter) with the whole trigger. If you want to know how generate a trigger dynamically, put *that* in your question. You say *"I cannot modify GetInsertTrigger"* but it is broken beyond belief, you need to fix it, not work around it.

Comment: @Charlieface It is a legacy code(I Can't do anything). And Yes it returns the code of a trigger as a resultset.

Comment: Then there is nothing you can do from T-SQL, you cannot nest `INSERT EXEC`. You will have to return the resultset to a client app such as C# or Python and aggregate it there. Note that `GO` is a batch-separator, you need to remove that before executing from client applications